# EF Code First One to (One or Zero) with string as primary key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, one-to-one, ef-fluent-api

I keep getting errors when I try to link up these two classes for the data structure. One has a string as a primary key and the other has a long. I've tried data annotations and other various things.

Fluent API or Data Annotations are acceptable.

Here's a sample of the one class:

```
public class X
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Token { get; set; }
    public virtual Y Y { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the other class:

```
public class Y
{
    [Key, StringLength(64), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public string Token { get; set; }

    public long XId { get; set; }
    public virtual X X{ get; set; }
}
```

And here is where I'm trying to define fkeys in OnModelCreating():

```
modelBuilder.Entity<X>()
            .HasOptional(u => u.Y)
            .WithRequired(u => u.X)
            .Map(m => m.MapKey("Token"));

modelBuilder.Entity<Y>()
            .HasRequired(u => u.X)
            .WithOptional(u => u.Y)
            .Map(m => m.MapKey("XId"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class X
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    // you don't need Token here...
    //public string Token { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("X")]
    public virtual Y Y { get; set; }
}

public class Y
{

    [Key, Column(Order=1)]
    public long XId {get;set;}

    [Index(Unique = true), StringLength(64)] 
    public string Token { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("XId")]
    [InverseProperty("Y")]
    public virtual X X{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This without Fluent API?

Comment: Yes, all you need is "InverseProperty", if set correctly, you don't need fluent api.

Comment: `XId` shouldn't be a key on class `Y` though. The only key in `Y` is `Token`.

Comment: For One to Zero or One, your foreign key must be primary key, otherwise EF will not accept, either way, in Fluent or in Data annotation. Try to look at it, if there is only one Y for X, XId will always be unique. If XId is duplicated, then it is one to many relation not one to zero or one.

Comment: You can keep Token as another Index with Unique as true. It means same, whether Token is Primary key or unique index, the only thing is, EF will want ForeignKey to be primary key.